How to link Power BI to Azure Log Analytics Workspace to analyze data from LAW in Power BI?
Does anyone know or have a link to the documentation which describes of how to connect Power BI to Azure Log Analytic Workspace Query (permanently) to be able to analyze LAW data in Power BI on a daily basis ?
Thanks in advance!
Export data to Excel first but I need a continuous access in Power BI to LAW data without exporting and importing data each time I need to analyze them.

azure portal -> your log analytics workspace -> code a simple query -> Share(at right-up ) -> export to Powerbi (as M query)

Thanks for the inputs @wenbo and I did the same way by following below steps:
Firstly after executing the Query In Log Analytics Workspace:

Click on Export
Then click on Power Bi (as M query):


Now a M query will be downloaded and copy that.
Steps in Power Bi:

Open Power Bi Desktop and Click on Blank Report



Now click on  Get Data and then click on Blank Query



Then in Blank Query Dialog Box click on Advanced Editor



Now paste the M query as below, next click on done and then enter credentials of azure account


Output:

One another way is by try using Azure Data explorer( i.e by sending the data to Azure Data Explorer and then use the cluster in Power Bi. )

thank you! Could you tell me if I need a Power BI Premium for that purpose? As I checked on this video manual on YouTube - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTc4OGbt80w - I would need Power BI Premium to connect Power BI with Log Anaytics Workspace (LAW) to analyze LAW data in Power BI?

No i have used normal basic Power Bi, try it with it, if it does not work then use premium. Try to use my steps, as in my steps i have used basic plan

@RithwikBojja done
